# High-pass filter without floating point

Tags: lua, signal-processing

I want to implement an High-pass filter on a ARM controller board with no floating point.

Already got an simple Low-pass filter, it's good enough.

This is the Low-pass filter:

```
binfilter = 0
function lowPassFilterBinary( input)
    binfilter = binfilter - ( bit.rshift( binfilter, 4) ) + input
    return bit.rshift( binfilter, 4)
end
```

How could I set up an High-pass filter under this circumstances?

Edit:
fixed inhouse bitwise operator << to reference function bit.lshift

Comment: Is `new` the input? Just wanted to make sure.

Comment: That looks unstable.  are you sure you don't mean bit.rshift?

Comment: @MattTimmermans - `bit.arshift` would fit better

Comment: `HPF(f) = f - LPF(f)`

Comment: @EgorSkriptunoff right you are -- I don't know Lua